# Json parse and push web sql database in Sapui5

Tags: ajax, cordova, sapui5, web-sql

I will design a a sample. My project will take all json data and insert to my web sql database.Firstly I used ajax for take my data and tried parse it. When I parsed , I dont access my json fields.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

var aData = jQuery
        .ajax({

            url : "http://../DataSource?format=json&key....", 

            dataType : "json",

            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
                var JsonData = data;
                oModel.setData(JsonData); 

            },

            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }

        });

obj = JSON.parse(oModel);
var myTextField = obj.Name;// This is not working 
console.log(myTextField);
```

Also ı tried this.

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    model.loadData("http://.../DataSource?format=json&key=...");
    obj = JSON.parse(model);
    var myTextField = obj.Name;
    console.log(myTextField);
```

This my database. I want insert all  name and surname field.

```
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emre');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emre (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO emre (id, data) VALUES (?,?)', [ name ,
            surname ]);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to try parsing the model, but that is not a JSON structure but a UI5 object which happen to contain the JSON structure.

But why would you parse the JSON in the first olace?? If your AJAX call finishes successfully, and stores the retrieved data in your model, you can simply access it from the model using

```
model.getProperty("/path/to/your/property");
```

Have a look at the model API in the docs, there it is all well explained

---

**EDIT** to get to the data after it is loaded, use the `attachRequestCompleted` event handler:

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(); 
model.attachRequestCompleted( function(){
    console.log(model.getProperty("Name"));
});
model.loadData("http:.../DataSource?format=json&key=...);
```

Comment: I have so many name field. How can insert all name fields to my database ?

Comment: model.getData() will get you the complete JSON structure of your model

Comment: `var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    model.loadData("http://.../DataSource?format=json&key=....");
    console.log(model.getProperty("Name")); ` I tried this but  return "undefined"

Comment: Yes of course, because you call `model.getProperty("Name")` right after the **asynchronous** load of `model.loadData`. You should use the `attachRequestCompleted` event handler to process your data once it is fully loaded

Comment: Thx your comments but ıt still didnt work. I tried this code.`var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
model.attachRequestCompleted(
          function(){
           model.loadData("http:.../DataSource?format=json&key=...);
     });
console.log(model.getProperty("Name")); 
`

Comment: No that is still incorrect... If you take a close look at your code, you're now waiting for a request to be finished which will never start because the loading itself is in the requestCompleted event handler. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried attachRequestCompleted  with alert and build succesfully. But ı am taking null error in console log . I think console log not taking fields.

Comment: If your `Name` property is part of an array, then you should adress it accordingly: `/0/Name`, or is at the root of your JSON response, use `/Name`. It really depends on the structure of your JSON how you should construct the path to your property

Comment: I'm grateful. I think this problem all night, you save my life:)